# Non-admins not authorized to create entry via frontend

Tags: upload, permissions, frontend-form

I'm currently working on a page that should allow registered users to upload an image and save it as an entry in a section called "bildupload", together with some additional fields.

Creating/saving the entry works just fine as long as I am logged in as an administrator, however, when logging in as a regular user, Craft throws an error telling me that I am not authorized and lack rights to access the page.

[image: Those are the permissions assigned to the default-usergroup]

Above image shows what permissions the default-user currently has.

I tried adding some permissions, however I does not make a difference, the error still appears on submitting the form to upload/create an entry.

Any help?

Comment: Do you have CSRF protection enabled and if so are you passing a token?

Answer (score 1):

Craft won't allow any anonymous entry creation at all.

You can use something like the [Guest Entries](https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries) plugin that simulates an "anonymous" entry because you select a user account ahead of time to assign all anonymously created entries to.